# how to change css of permanent item when scroll using react

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

how can I change div's height on scroll while i'm using react???

```
<div id="navigation"></div>
```

css:

```
#navigation{
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: Make your question more  clear

Comment: using jquery to change div's height will have to use add class, which can't work for react. @artgb

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain Javascript, with event listeners. Change the state based on how far was scrolled and toggle a class. Here's an example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      hasScrolled: false,
    };
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  handleScroll() {
    let hasScrolled = true;

    // Check if it was scrolled back to the top.
    if (document.body.scrollTop <= 20) {
      hasScrolled = false;
    }

    this.setState({ hasScrolled });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Listen on scrolling event, call our function.
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // Unlisten if the component unmounts.
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  render() {
    // Add className to the navigation based on our state.
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          id="navigation"
          className={this.state.hasScrolled ? 'onscroll' : null}
        />

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
          nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
          sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
          rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
          ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
          sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
          dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam
          et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
          takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
#navigation {
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
  transition: .2s ease height;
}

#navigation.onscroll {
  height: 30px;
}

p {
  margin: 80px 20px;
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: how can i add this to here? @fabian schultz <script type="text/babel">
      var Nav = React.createClass({
          render: function () {
              return(
                    <div id="navigation">
                    
                    </div>

              )
          }
      });
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Nav />,
            document.getElementById('navigation-bar')
        );